# CF10 / IIS7.5 - cffile read file outside of web root

Tags: coldfusion, iis-7.5, coldfusion-10

CF10 on Win 2K8 with IIS 7.5.  My webroot is d:\web[sitename] with [sitename] being a folder for the actual site.

I want to read a .txt file stored elsewhere - say d:\web\somefile.txt or d:\somefile.txt, but seemingly no matter what permissions I give the file or it's parent folder I keep getting a file not found error:

```
 An error occurred when performing a file operation read on file d:/web/somefile.txt.
The cause of this exception was: java.io.FileNotFoundException: d:/web/somefile.txt (The system cannot find the file specified).
```

My CF service runs as a specific user and I've given that user everything from read to full control of that file and still no dice.  My IIS app pool also runs as a specific user and adding permissions for it also doesn't help.

Is this something with Tomcat that I need to configure?  If so, how?

Comment: Can you perform a cfdirectory on d:\web?

Comment: Did you find a solution. I'm getting the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may have sandbox security enabled which is preventing CF from reading the file. Log into the CF administrator and check it that.

Comment: It is not enabled.  I used your Lockdown guide as well but even with "Everyone" and full control of the file set I still get the 500 error / file not found.  Inside the webroot it reads fine.